# Elasticsearch installation and MySQL RDS

Tags: database, elasticsearch, aws

I have elasticsearch installed in the same Magento 2.4 instant, but my MySQLdatabase is on AWS RDS, How should I configure elasticsearch?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq-elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the config as per you ES instance:
for example:

```
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Comment: `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7`